# Custom number of buttons tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

How can I create custom buttons tinymce buttons using JQuery? I would need n "Menu item" buttons. "n" would be defined depending on the selected data before opening the tinymce editor.

My buttons:

```
editor.addButton('addButtons', {
        type: 'menubutton',
        text: 'My button',
        icon: false,
        menu: [
            {
                text: 'Menu item 1',
                onclick: function() {
                    editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<strong>item1</strong>&nbsp;');
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Menu item 2',
                onclick: function() {
                    editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<strong>item2</strong>&nbsp;');
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Menu item 3',
                onclick: function() {
                    editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<strong>item3</strong>&nbsp;');
                }
            }
        ] 
    });
```

I can get "n" value from a input type hidden using JQuery `$("#totalButtons").val()`. If totalButtons is 4, I would need 4 item buttons. Does it make sense? Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Updated Code:

```
var n = $('#total').val();
var menuItems = [];

  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextareaTenant',
    content_css: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aguafina+Script|Alex+Brush|Bilbo|Condiment|Great+Vibes|Herr+Von+Muellerhoff|Kristi|Meddon|Monsieur+La+Doulaise|Norican|Nothing+You+Could+Do|Parisienne|Permanent+Marker|Sacramento|Yellowtail',
    theme: 'modern',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        "print"
    ],           

    setup: function (editor) { 
        editor.on('init', function (e) {
            renderEditorTenant();

            for (var i=1; i<=n; i++){
                var msg = '&nbsp;<strong>#item' + i + '#</strong>&nbsp;';
                var obj = {
                    text: 'Menu item ' + i,
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.insertContent(msg);
                    }
                }
                menuItems.push(obj);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This should help: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/toolbarbuttons/#howtocreatecustomtoolbarbuttons

Comment: No, it just say how to create the button. If you look at my code, I already have it. I need to set the number of buttons according to users input

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have a hidden input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="zyx" value="3" />
```

You can get the value of the input and generate an array with `n` elements:

```
var n = $('#foo').val();
var menuItems = [];

for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
  var msg = '&nbsp;<strong>item' + i + '</strong>&nbsp;';
  var obj = {
    text: 'Menu item ' + i,
    onclick: function() {
        editor.insertContent(msg);
    }
}
  menuItems.push(obj);
}
```

Now, just pass this array to the function you're using to generate the editor:

```
editor.addButton('addButtons', {
        type: 'menubutton',
        text: 'My button',
        icon: false,
        menu: menuItems
    });
```

Comment: It is very helpful; however, I get the error: "editor is not defined" when I click on the button.

Comment: in that case, I guess the code you provide in the original question with 3 static items is not working either. Have you checked the documentation for TinyMCE? Can you provide a minimal, reproductible example? (pls see https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: The code is working. I think the problem is that the var menuItems is being created before the tinymce.init(), so we do not have the editor at that time.

Comment: is your code inside a tinymce.init({}) block? https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#addbutton

Comment: I just updated the code to show how I inserted your code inside my tinymce. When I click on Menu item 1, it insert the text item2 instead of item1. Why is it happening?